# Querying Android ContentResolver for gallery files and determining image vs video

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple Android app for my own phone that looks at my Gallery, and for each image/video file:

- creates a `Bitmap` thumbnail of the file
- records the file's absolute path on the phone

Essentially, I'll have the following data model:

```
public class MediaFileModel {

  private Bitmap thumbnail;
  private String absPath;

  // ctor, getters and setters omitted for brevity
  
}
```

And I need something that looks at all the files in my Gallery and yields a `List<MediaFileModel>`. My best attempt is here:

```
public List<MediaFileModel> getAllGalleryMedia() {

  String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
  List<MediaFileModel> galleryMedia = new ArrayList<>();
  Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    null);

  // I believe here I'm iterating over all the gallery files (???)
  while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    MediaFileModel next = new MediaFileModel();

    // is this how I get the abs path of the current file?!?
    String absPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));

    Bitmap thumbnail = null;
    if (true /* ??? cursor is pointing to a media file that is an image/photo ??? */) {
      thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absPath), 64, 64);
    } else {
      // else we have a video (I assume???)
      thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(absPath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    }

    next.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
    next.setAbsPath(absPath);

    galleryMedia.add(next);
    
  }

  return galleryMedia;
  
}
```

However I'm not sure if my media query is setup correctly and I'm definitely not sure how to determine whether the file is an image/photo of a video, which I (*believe* I) need so that I can use the correct method for obtaining the thumbnail `Bitmap`.

**Can anyone help nudge me over the finish line here?**

Comment: You can check if the absolute path's file extension (the characters following the last `.`, i.e. `png` in `/absolute/path/to/file/image.png`) ends in a known image file extension, such as `png`, `bmp`, `jpg`, etc. to differentiate between images and videos. You'll probably also want to check the video file extensions as well for `mp4`, `gif`, `mov`, etc., you may have files other than images and videos which you'll want to skip over.

Comment: MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps (+1) -- do I add `MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE` to the query somehow (if so, _how?_) or can I find it as a property on each `cursor` position's object (if so, _how_?)

Comment: Well.. how did you investigate MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA ? For Android 10+ devices use .DISPLAY_NAME and .RELATIVE.PATH instead of .DATA.

Comment: So it _sounds_ like you are saying that I should define my projection as `String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE };`, but I still don't see how/where I can use the `MIME_TYPE` for each record (that the `cursor` iterates over) to decide image vs video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code I was using for something similar, I hope this will help:

```
//The code has been removed
```

Note: Sorry I've removed the code because I am not sure if it has some portion copied from other open-sourced codes, I am using it in my apps but I can't remember if it is quoted from other source, so I've removed it, also it could be auto-completed using `github copilot`

Comment: Thanks @Jabbar (+1) -- what is `images.clear();` above the `imagecursor` definition?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup you can ignore it, it is a list I am updating with the collected images or videos, the clear is to empty the list before getting data

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup so how did you end up doing this?